# Enhancing Vim gf command for ruby: include module syntax

Tags: vimrc, filetype-ruby

I am looking for a way to enhance vim gf command

```
class Myclass
  include Mymodules::HardToFind
end
```

I have started with installing [tpope/rails-vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails):

> Easy navigation of the Rails directory structure. gf considers context
>   and knows about partials, fixtures, and much more.

But I think I have a problem with path variable in my vim.

When my cursor is a the beginning of the **include** and I hit gf I am getting:

```
E345: Can't find file "include" in path
```

When I move it at the beginning of **Mymodules::HardToFind** I am getting:

```
E345: Can't find file "mymodules/hard_to_find.rb" in path
```

- So the first problem is the path - How should I configure it?
- Second one is it possible to have the file loaded regardless of the cursor position in a given line?